# Periodically save Generated HTML to local file

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, dom

OK, so this what I'm trying to do - and I'm open to suggestions.

- I open up a webpage (in Chrome/Firefox - doesn't matter)
- The webpage contains self-updating AJAX, which means the generated html/dom changes like every minute
- I want to be able to *automatically* (no `save as`, no nothing) save the source locally

How can this be done?

---

P.S. I've been playing with the .js console, firebug, etc. But I'm still not sure how to go about this. So any suggestion is more than welcome! :-)

Comment: @Teemu Sounds more like I'm planning to scrape a seemingly-unscrapeable page :-)

Comment: Well you can use localStorage to store the output on the machine and later retrive it by key. But could you explain why you want this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this snippet to save the HTML source on HD using JS, here `document.documentElement.outerHTML` is used to get the HTML source for the page:-

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    function SaveToDisk(sPath)
    {
        var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        var fileDest = fso.CreateTextFile(sPath, true);
        if (fileDest)
        {
           fileDest.Write(document.documentElement.outerHTML);
           fileDest.close();
        }
        else
        {
           alert("unable to create file " + sPath);
        }

    }        
</script>
</HEAD>

<BODY onload="SaveToDisk('c:\\temp\\123.htm');">
<P>The rest of the page is here...</P>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

There is also a solution available where you can save source for another website by providing the url , check [this](http://p2p.wrox.com/javascript-how/3193-how-do-you-save-html-page-your-local-hd.html)

Answer (score 0):

For chrome, open the js console and enter:

```
window.open('data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + escape(document.documentElement.outerHTML));
```

Then you can save the generated html. It may also work in other browsers.